# html: how can I show text in html "textarea" ie "value" setting?

Tags: html

I want to do the following with "value":

```
<textarea type="text" name="message"rows="10" cols="10" value="hi there"></textarea></p>
```

thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<textarea type="text" name="message"rows="10" cols="10">Hi there</textarea>
```

Don't use the 'value' attribute, put the text in the element (i.e. there is no 'value' attribute for this HTML element, AFAICR)

Comment: can i put a variable in there somehow.  I want the contents of the variable to show...thanks

Comment: What kind of variable? PHP - Yes, quite easy. JS - yes, but less easy (if the variable is changing)

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea type="text" name="message"rows="10" cols="10">hi there</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add text between the `textarea` tags as follows:

`<textarea>My placeholder Value</textarea>`